# Html div content include with input text value to pdf using java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

html div content include with input text value to pdf using java script??

My html body is something look like,

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="3">
      <table><tr>
          <td></td><td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td><td></td>
      </tr></table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td><td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#exportpdf").click(function() {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'ledger');
                // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
                // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
                source = $('#tableresponsive')[0];

                // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style 
                // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
                // There is no support for any other type of selectors 
                // (class, of compound) at this time.
                specialElementHandlers = {
                    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
                    '#bypassme' : function(element, renderer) {
                        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                        return true
                    }
                };
                margins = {
                    top : 80,
                    bottom : 60,
                    left : 60,
                    width : 522
                };
                // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
                // 'inches' in this case
                pdf.fromHTML(source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
                margins.left, // x coord
                margins.top, { // y coord
                    'width' : margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                    'elementHandlers' : specialElementHandlers
                },

                function(dispose) {
                    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
                    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                    pdf.save('fileNameOfGeneretedPdf.pdf');
                }, margins);
            });

        }); </script>
```

tableresponsive is table id and exportpdf is button id.It generates pdf but,text and content are spread in the pdf.Lots of `','` also in generated pdf.
Please, tell me how to generate this type of pdf with including input text values??

Used Plugins for jspdf:

```
<script src='/static/jspdf.min.js'></script>
<script src='/static/jspdf.debug.js'></script>
```